# Make a Weekly Folder With VBA Script/Scheduled Task

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I'm trying to make an automatic folder generation process per week. We have timesheets coming in and we have to put them into an organised folder structure (it's on a shared drive, so for example: Y:\Timesheets\2013-09-22" (for timesheets for the week ending the 22nd of September)). That folder will then have folders relating to the employee names.

We use an excel tick sheet which is up to date all of the time with the latest information to make sure that we have received the timesheets. I was thinking that I could make an automatic folder generation process per week, rather than copying and pasting every empty folder from next week to the week after (as it transfers a lot of old folders which are simply not used).

So far I can create folders with this:

```
Sub CreateDirs()

    createDirsFromRange "Z:\Timesheets", "2013-10-13", Range("B2:B182")

End Sub
```

My only questions are:

1. Can I make the date part of that code get the date from the PC (and therefore run it every Sunday) to make sure we have the correct title for each folder?
2. Could I run a batch file to open the Excel spreadsheet, run the VBA code and then close it again? If so, what would the coding for that be?

Comment: What is **createDirsFromRange** ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the `Date()` function (see [this link](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html) for more options)
2. A solution could be :

In your batch, just run excel giving it your workbook filename as parameter :

```
"C:\Program Files\...\excel.exe" "C:\...\myworkbook.xls"
```

Then, you can use the [Workbook.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215.aspx) event and the [Workbook.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx) function so that your macro runs everytime the workbook is opened (so you just have to open it with your batch file).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    ' Call your macro here
    ThisWorkbook.Close()
End Sub
```

But this means the macro will run everytime so you won't be able to open the workbook without having the macro run and the workbook automaticaly closed...

So you may consider using a specific command line argument to trigger the macro execution (see [this link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?366559-Excel-How-to-Pass-Command-Line-Parameter-DKenny-is-KING!))

Answer (score 0):

As far as 1) is concerned, change the date string to `Date$`, which will give you the current date in an acceptable format (mm-dd-yyyy).

As far as 2) is concerned, instead of trying to automate that part of it, why not just run the code on Friday at the end of business or sometime on Friday while the file is open? You could use this code for your date (to show the date for Sunday instead of Friday): `mid(date$,1,3) & mid(date$,4,2)+2 & mid(date$,6,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're in a Windows environment.  If so, why not just use Windows Task Scheduler?  It's built in, and you can tell it to kick off your Excel sheet (or a BAT file) every Sunday or whatever day of the week you want it to.

Here's a link to the [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) version.  And another for the [Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) version.

Here's a link to a really good page on how to extract the [current date using a BAT file](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000987.htm).  You can probably figure out how to edit it to suit your needs.